# revoke user access / drop user from Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

As some team members have left the company, for safety reasons, I need to drop the user out of the database in Redshift.
I have tried

```
drop user person_username;
```

It returns "user `person_username` cannot be dropped because the user owns some object"

I believe

```
select relname, relkind
from pg_catalog.pg_class
where relowner = (select usesysid from pg_catalog.pg_user where usename = 'person_username');
```

shows the list of tables owned by `person_username`.

However, I am still unable to achieve the goal:
`person_username` should not be able to access the database anymore, for whatever reason.

Note: The person should not be able to access all the schemas and all the tables, so specifying the schema one by one is not a solution I prefer.

Answer (score 1):

AWS has the article about it https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/redshift-user-cannot-be-dropped

In general you need create two views

- [v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl.sql](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl.sql)
- [v_find_dropuser_objs.sql](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_find_dropuser_objs.sql)

It will return ddl's for altering user-owned objects to another user or admin.

```sql
select ddl || '<another_username>;' as ddl
from admin.v_find_dropuser_objs
where objowner = '<username>';
```

It will return ddl's for revoking user permission.

```sql
select ddl
from admin.v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl
where ddltype = 'revoke'
  and ddl ilike '%<username>%'
```